# Combine associated model data through foreign key with model in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, Tweets and TweetsLocations, associated to each other with:

```
class Tweets < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, :primary_key => "twitter_message_id",
                     :foreign_key => "twitter_message_id"
```

And:

```
class TweetsLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tweet
```

If I load a Tweet, like `@tweet = Tweet.find(1)`, I can see all the attributes of it with no problem. If I want to see the associated Location attributes, I can with `@tweet.location`, again with no problem.

But if I wanted to have a JSON array of all @tweet(s) that included the associated attributes from Locations--is this possible elegantly, or do I need to create a new array of "tweets_with_locations" with the tweets and attributes from my Locations model built into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to include the TweetsLocation object in your JSON output you can use the `:include` option to `as_json`, e.g.:

```
@tweet = Tweet.find 1
@tweet.as_json :include => :location
```

If, however, you want to include the TweetsLocation's attributes as though they were attributes of the Tweet itself it's a little more complicated, but you have a couple options:

First, you can delegate the desired attributes to TweetsLocation, e.g.:

```
class Tweets < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, :primary_key => "twitter_message_id",
                     :foreign_key => "twitter_message_id"

  # if TweetsLocation has e.g. "name" and "coordinates" attributes
  delegate :coordinates, :name, :to => :location, :prefix => true
end
```

This way `@tweet.as_json`'s output will have `location_name` and `location_coordinates` keys.

Secondly, you can override `as_json` to do massage the JSON output in any way you want, e.g.:

```
class Tweets < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def as_json options = {}
    # just merge all of TweetsLocation's attributes into the output
    attributes.merge(location.attributes).to_json options
  end
end
```